# Rails and build:css via rails assets:precompile on Heroku/production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tailwind-css

I have the `package.json` & `build:css` scripts in it.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:css": "tailwindcss --postcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application_compiled.css"
  },
```

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` I see that  `/app/assets/builds/application_compiled.css` is **NOT** generated. It seems like `build:css` has not been triggered. This leads to:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application_compiled.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

Which script should run `build:css` script in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was enhancing precompile script manually.

```
task :before_assets_precompile do
  # run a command which starts your packaging
  system("yarn run build:css")
end

Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance ["before_assets_precompile"]
```

It was hard for me to figure out what was not working because `./bin/dev` script created file in `/app/assets/builds` folder. That is why compilation worked on localhost but not on production. When testing compilation process it is the best to turn off dev server and delete files in `/app/assets/builds` and in `/public/assets/`. If compilation works, you should end up with compiled files in `/public/assets` folder.

It is worth mentioning that `app/assests/config/manifest.js` should be configured properly. If not - you will probably end up with `ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application_compiled.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.`